# How can a title remain at the bottom of a descriptive hover box that has a transform scale?

Tags: css

I am trying to get the title to stick to the bottom of the hover box, so that when the user hovers over the title, the hover box appears with the title on the bottom. It should close from the title upwards, so that the entire box is covered by the description, but the title remains on the bottom. How do I get the hover box to appear with the title not moving?

I attached my code below so that you can see what I am talking about. When you hover over the h1 pictureTitle, it goes towards the middle of the picture because of the transform effect. I want it to remain at the bottom, and have the black background close upwards from the title, so that the hover box seems like it is a part of the title.

```css
 .img__wrap {
      position: relative;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .picture {
      width: 200px;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
    }

    .img__description {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      color: #fff;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.2s;
      visibility:hidden;
    }


    .img__wrap:hover .img__description {
      opacity: 1;
      background:black;
      height:100%;
      visibility:visible;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }

    .img__wrap:hover .picture {
      -moz-transform: scale(1.8);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
      transform: scale(1.8);
    }

    .pictureTitle{
    background:black;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:70px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="img__wrap">
      <a href="myHomePage.html" style="text-decoration:none;">
        <img src="http://www.dogbreedplus.com/dog_names/images/puppy-dog-names.jpg" alt="hover box is supposed to encapsulate picture"
        class="picture">
        <p class="img__description">
          This is where the hover box should pop up explaining the picture it should flow from title and cover the box.
        </p>
      <h1 class="pictureTitle">Title </h1>
     
      </a>
      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Title stay `bottom` issue**

The title is staying in the same position. It doesn't move. You need to move it together with the image resizing. As the image is resizing to cover the full `img__wrap` div, you should change the `bottom` value of the `pictureTitle` from `70px` to `0px` and also add a transition to it. And so, it will move together with the image and always position it self at the bottom of the image

So your question is a wrong. You have to move the title otherwise it will stay in the same position as initially set.

**2. Expand black background from bottom to top**

Here is another problem with your code. You want to transition `visibility:hidden` to `visibility: visible` . This is not possible because you cannot animate non numeric values like `visibility:hidde/visible` or `display:none/block`. You should just use `opacity:0` and `opacity:1` on hover.

Then position the `img__description` at the bottom ( `bottom:0` without `top:0` ) and add an initial height of `0px` . Then at hover add `height:100%`

Let me know if you have other questions. Cheers! :D

```css
.img__wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 190px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.picture {
  width: 200px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.img__description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
  height: 0;
}

.img__wrap:hover .img__description {
  opacity: 1;
  height: 100%;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

.img__wrap:hover .picture {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.8);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.8);
  transform: scale(1.8);
}

.pictureTitle {
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.img__wrap:hover .pictureTitle {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img__wrap">
  <a href="myHomePage.html" style="text-decoration:none;">
    <img src="http://www.dogbreedplus.com/dog_names/images/puppy-dog-names.jpg" alt="hover box is supposed to encapsulate picture" class="picture">
    <p class="img__description">
      This is where the hover box should pop up explaining the picture it should flow from title and cover the box.
    </p>
    <h1 class="pictureTitle">Title </h1>

  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Yep! That is it!

Comment: Feel free to explain further if you want. That is exactly what I was after. Checking out some of the mods you made right now.

Comment: @QuestForMastery . I edited my answer with explanation. If this answer solved your problem, please don't forget to rate/accept it accordingly . Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 0):

use picture of 200x200 if your want to use height or for now add **height:200px** to class .picture image will stretch but it will resolve your problem, so instead of this use a perfect image 200x200

Comment: That is very close to what I am after. But now the hover box does not entirely cover the picture on the top. Any idea why?

Comment: add margin:0 to class .img__description